# leResize the image to new height and width but do not exceed original height and width

Tags: php, image, laravel, resize

In PHP Need to resize the image to new height and width but not to cross the original image.The example I need to resize the image to 200 *200.But actually, the image size is 150*150 then resizing not to happen.

- If the image size is 300*300 then need to resize to 200*200.
- If image size in 300*150 then it resizes to 200*150.

Can anyone help on this issue.If there any plugin available

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you show the code you are using right now? Furthermore, you realize that you will distort the images by resizing from 300x150 to 200x150?

Answer (score 1):

here is some psuedo-code that may illustrate a possible path of logic:

```
function resizeMyImage($incImage){
  $imageRatio;
  $maxSize = 200;
  $originalX;
  $originalY;
  $newX;
  $newY;

  $newX = $originalX = imageSize.x;
  $newY = $originalY = imageSize.y;
  $imageRatio = imageSize.x / imageSize.y;

  if($imageRatio >= 1){
   // height is greater than (or equal to) width
   if($newX > $maxSize){
     return false;
   }else{
     $newX = $maxSize;
     $newY = $newX / $imageRatio;
   }
  }else{
   // width is greater than height
   if($newY > $maxSize){
     return false;
   }else{
     $newY = $maxSize;
     $newX = $newY * $imageRatio;
   }
  }
  resizeTheImage($newX,$newY);
}
```

this is psuedocode and will not work, but it is a fast example of resizing images with a max width or height while maintaining the aspect ratio.

I would look at your code and write a workable example, but you did not provide any.  I hope this helps.